# Compiling a project with paths

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2008

I have an old qt project folder in QT  version 4.8.5 with visual studio 2008. Now i installed the versions with the addin 1.1.11. The project itself has a lot of paths of the form "../../path" that he includes in the same folder (all the files exist).

The problem is that the compiler is not finding them because starts searching for them starting from the path where visual studio 2008 is installed. 6 years ago this project was running just fine so I do not think the project itself has a problem.

Did somebody has encountered with this problem?

Comment: You didn't actually ask a question.

Comment: The problem was the question but whatever...Fix it.

Comment: Do the folders still exist?  If so, you will need to change the paths in the project to point to the folders.  (This is the sort of thing I prefer to do with a text editor, rather than a "helpful" GUI - I like to be able to control exactly what is stored in the project, rather than having the GUI guess what I wanted.)

Comment: Yes, all folder exist and are in order. I have a root folder that contains multiple folders with multiple files and other folders.

Comment: Your assumption that the compiler starts searching for include files is the path of the compiler is wrong.